# Add text in file before every matched string value

Tags: sql-server, powershell, text, replace, append

I have this SQL file with the CREATE statements for 697 stored procedures in it, but unfortunately it won't execute due to a syntax problem.

The script requires a `GO` statement between every `CREATE PROCEDURE` call.

The question is: how do I add `GO` before every `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement?

I am looking to achieve this through the use of PowerShell code.

The `Select-String` might guide us in the right direction as it is able to find the 697 stored procedures in the SQL file. The below returned a count of 697. But not sure how to use this to add text in front of every finding.

```
(Select-String -Path $sqlFile -Pattern "CREATE PROCEDURE" -AllMatches).Matches.Count
```

I also tried to replace text in the file with the below command

```
(Get-Content $sqlFile).replace('CREATE PROCEDURE', ' GO CREATE PROCEDURE') | Set-Content $sqlFile
```

This however resulted in an error when executing the SQL script:

> A fatal scripting error occurred. Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing GO

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `GO` ***IS NOT** a SQL statement! It's a **delimiter** used by SQL Server Management Studio and some Microsoft libraries in the SQL Server space - but it's SQL Server specific and **not** a standardized SQL element at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is found. Use the `` `n ``character.

```
(Get-Content $sqlFile).replace('CREATE PROCEDURE', " GO `n CREATE PROCEDURE") | Set-Content $sqlFile
```

Comment: Nice, though note that `\`n` isn't a _character_; it's an _escape sequence_ that expands to a LF character in an [expandable (interpolating) string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) in PowerShell. A slightly slower, but less repetitive solution based on the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) is: `(Get-Content $sqlFile) -replace 'CREATE PROCEDURE', " GO \`n \`$&" | Set-Content $sqlFile`